# How to create double nested JSON object?

Tags: php, json, object, nested, phpexcel

my problem is how to add `CUSTOM_FIELD` or other double nested JSON like `ADDRESS` using PHP classes provided at Github/insightly:

```
$contact = (object)array('ADDRESSES' =>(object) array('ADDRESS_TYPE' => 'POSTAL','COUNTRY' => $data[4])); 
$contact = $this->addContact($contact); 
$data = json_encode($contact); 
print_r($data);
```

I am trying to create the object from below JSON:

```
{   
    "FIRST_NAME": "Andy",
    "LAST_NAME": "Nguyen",
    "BACKGROUND": "McD is a fast food company with lot of franchies around the world",
    "VISIBLE_TO": "EVERYONE",
    "CUSTOMFIELDS": [
      {
        "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "CONTACT_FIELD_1",
        "FIELD_VALUE": "Industry"
      },
      {
      "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "CONTACT_FIELD_2",
        "FIELD_VALUE": "Range of Investment"
      },
      {
        "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "CONTACT_FIELD_3",
        "FIELD_VALUE": "https://www.McD.com"
      },
      {
        "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "CONTACT_FIELD_4",
        "FIELD_VALUE": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5vykgsxhfi7x6c/McD%202017%20ASEAN%20Food%20In%20Asia.pdf?dl=3"
      }
    ],
    "ADDRESSES": [
      {
        "ADDRESS_TYPE": "POSTAL", 
        "COUNTRY": "Malaysia"
      }
    ],
    "CONTACTINFOS": [
      {
        "TYPE": "EMAIL",
        "LABEL": "WORK",
        "DETAIL": "Andy@Mcd.com"
      }
    ],
    "LINKS": [
      {
        "OPPORTUNITY_ID": null,
        "ORGANISATION_ID": 106787363,
        "ROLE": "CEO",
      }
    ],
  }
```

However the data source is in Excel Format. So I use PHPExcel to convert it into JSON format and send it to another function that performs JSON ENCODE.

I am using `Stdclass()` like below:

```
$contact = new stdClass();
$contact->CUSTOMFIELDS -> CUSTOM_FIELD_ID = "CONTACT_FIELD_1";
$contact->CUSTOMFIELDS -> CUSTOM_FIELD_ID = $data;
```

but it doesn't work because they read it as a string not as an object, can anyone help me?

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. Do you want to convert the json into an object? What is the code that is trying to perform JSON ENCODE? Did you do `json_decode(json_encode($data));`, assuming $data is the above json

Comment: You could try [SimpleXMLReader](https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader) extends the XMLReader class native to PHP 5+.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply @ayip... yes i want to convert JSON code into an object however, my data input variable was input from PHPexcel.       
   so my problem is how to add CUSTOME_FIELD or other double nested JSON like ADDRESS using PHP classes provide at [link] (https://github.com/Insightly/insightly-php):     $contact = (object)array('ADDRESSES' =>(object) array('ADDRESS_TYPE' => 'POSTAL','COUNTRY' => $data[4]));     $contact = $this->addContact($contact);                                    
 $data = json_encode($contact); print_r($data);